# Append oracle associative array in a loop to another associative array within that loop

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am trying to do to a bulk collect inside a loop which have dynamic SQL and execute multiple times based on input from loop then inserting into a table (and it is taking time approx. 4 mins to insert 193234 records).
So as to try different different approach I think of using the bulk collect on select inside the loop and fill up a collection with each iteration of that loop lets say 1st iteration gives 10 rows then second gives 0 rows and 3rd returns 15 rows then the collection should hold 15 records at end of the loop.
After exiting the loop I will use forall with collection I filled up inside loop to do an Insert at one go instead to doing insert for each iteration inside loop.

below is a sample code which is similar to application procedure I just use different tables to simplify question.

```
create table test_tab as select owner, table_name, column_name from all_tab_cols where 1=2;

create or replace procedure p_test
as

  l_sql varchar2(4000);
  type t_tab is table of test_tab%rowtype index by pls_integer;
  l_tab t_tab;
  l_tab1 t_tab;
  l_cnt number := 0;

begin

for i in (with tab as (select 'V_$SESSION' table_name from dual 
                       union all
                       select 'any_table'  from dual
                       union all
                       select 'V_$TRANSACTION' from dual
                       union all
                       select 'test_table' from dual
                       )
                    select table_name from tab )
loop
  
  l_sql := 'select owner, table_name, column_name from all_tab_cols where table_name = '''||i.table_name||'''';
  
 -- dbms_output.put_line(l_sql );
  execute immediate l_sql bulk collect into l_tab;
  
  dbms_output.put_line(l_sql ||' > '||l_tab.count);
  l_cnt := l_cnt +1;
  
  if l_tab.count<>0
  then
    l_tab1(l_cnt) := l_tab(l_cnt);
  end if;  
    
end loop;  
  dbms_output.put_line(l_tab1.count);
  forall i in indices of l_tab1
  insert into test_tab values (l_tab1(i).owner, l_tab1(i).table_name, l_tab1(i).column_name);

end;
```

It is inserting only 2 rows in test_tab table whereas as per my system it should insert 150 rows.

```
select owner, table_name, column_name from all_tab_cols where table_name = 'V_$SESSION' > 103
select owner, table_name, column_name from all_tab_cols where table_name = 'any_table' > 0
select owner, table_name, column_name from all_tab_cols where table_name = 'V_$TRANSACTION' > 47
select owner, table_name, column_name from all_tab_cols where table_name = 'test_table' > 0
2
```

Above is DBMS_OUTPUT from my system you may change the table names in loop if the example table names does not exists in your DB.

Oracle Version --

```
Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

***EDIT***
Below screenshot shows highlighted timings from PLSQL_PROFILER with Actual insert...select... written in procedure at line# 114 and with bulk collect and forall with nested table at line# 132 and multiset and seems like we are saving atleast 40 secs here with bulk collect, multiset and forall.

[image]

Comment: 1. What you are using inside `l_sql` is not a dynamic SQL, it should be a static SQL, because there's no dynamic **identifiers** in it. So it would be `select owner, table_name, column_name bulk collect into l_tab from all_tab_cols where table_name = i.table_name`. 2. Do not move the data back and forth if it doesn't require any PL/SQL processing. Use `insert into test_tab (<columns>) select <columns> from all_tab_cols where table_name in (<subquery that generates table names>)`

Comment: Just wondering: why don't you directly insert rows into TEST_TAB (as select from ALL_TAB_COLS)? I.e. use pure SQL instead of PL/SQL?

Comment: @astentx, thanks for reply I know my current SQL did not require dynamic SQL I just used it here to simplify example but in actual procedure the SQL is dynamic and currently it is written as insert into table select * from table only I just trying to do differently as current approach taking time to insert just only 193234 records.

Comment: So your real dynamic SQL uses dynamic table names and/or columns (not filter values) and you want to insert something based on this parameters passed externally, right?

Comment: @Littlefoot, thanks for reply currently it is written only as you said in comment but it taking time to insert so I thinking of trying some another approach to see if it helps :)

Comment: @astentx, yes actual is dynamic with dynamic columns is select statement its like a validation query where we fetch error for each columns for tables to generate fallout or say validation report after migration.

Comment: PL/SQL will close-to-always (if not always) be slower than pure SQL, so ... perhaps you'd rather tune query you currently use.

Comment: Yes that is right but in case if you can help me with some idea how I can make work my above procedure to insert all records then it will be a learning for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, do not use associative array collection for this, just use a nested-table collection type. You can concatenate nested-table collections using the `MULTISET UNION ALL` operator (avoiding needing to use loops).

```sql
CREATE TYPE test_type IS OBJECT(
  owner       VARCHAR2(30),
  table_name  VARCHAR2(30),
  column_name VARCHAR2(30)
);

CREATE TYPE test_tab_type IS TABLE OF test_type;
```

Then:

```sql
create procedure p_test
as
  l_sql CLOB := 'select test_type(owner, table_name, column_name) from all_tab_cols where table_name = :table_name';
  l_table_names SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST(
                                          'V_$SESSION',
                                          'ANY_TABLE',
                                          'V_$TRANSACTION',
                                          'TEST_TABLE'
                                        );
  l_tab  test_tab_type := test_tab_type();
  l_temp test_tab_type;
  l_cnt  number := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_table_names.COUNT LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql BULK COLLECT INTO l_temp USING l_table_names(i);
  
    dbms_output.put_line(
      l_sql || ': ' || l_table_names(i) || ' > '||l_temp.count
    );
    l_cnt := l_cnt +1;
    l_tab := l_tab MULTISET UNION ALL l_temp;  
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_tab.count);

  insert into test_tab
  SELECT *
  FROM   TABLE(l_tab);
end;
/
```

Secondly, don't do multiple queries if you can do it all in one query and use an `IN` statement; and if you do it all in a single statement then you do not need to worry about concatenating collections.

```sql
create or replace procedure p_test
as
  l_table_names SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST(
                                          'V_$SESSION',
                                          'ANY_TABLE',
                                          'V_$TRANSACTION',
                                          'TEST_TABLE'
                                        );
  l_tab  test_tab_type;
BEGIN
  select test_type(owner, table_name, column_name)
  bulk collect into l_tab
  from all_tab_cols
  where table_name IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(l_table_names));

  dbms_output.put_line(l_tab.count);

  insert into test_tab
  SELECT *
  FROM   TABLE(l_tab);
end;
/
```

Thirdly, if you can do `INSERT ... SELECT ...` in a single statement the it will be much faster than using `SELECT ... INTO ...` and then a separate `INSERT`; and doing that means you do not need to use any collections.

```sql
create or replace procedure p_test
as
begin
  INSERT INTO test_tab (owner, table_name, column_name)
  select owner, table_name, column_name
  from   all_tab_cols
  where  table_name IN (
           'V_$SESSION',
           'ANY_TABLE',
           'V_$TRANSACTION',
           'TEST_TABLE'
         );
end;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kgD2ZPEk)

Comment: Thanks for reply MTO, I just trying to do it differently like I said it is dynamic SQL in actual procedure so it can not be used as IN or other operator and currently we are using insert ... select... approach only.

Comment: @mradul Updated with examples at each level of simplicity. It will be most efficient if you use a single SQL statement and no dynamic SQL and least efficient using loops and concatenating collections.

Comment: Thanks the first Example is answer to my question :)

Comment: I have update the questing and added timings screenshot from PLSQL_PROFILER and it seems like with nested tables and forall 40 secs and being saved.

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle 19c I would suggest to use [`SQL_MACRO(table)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-elements.html#GUID-292C3A17-2A4B-4EFB-AD38-68DF6380E5F7) to build dynamic SQL in place and use plain SQL. Below is an example that builds dynamic SQL based on `all_tab_cols` but it may be any other logic to build such SQL (with known column names and column order). Then you may use `insert ... select ...` without PL/SQL, because SQL macro is processed at the query parsing time.

Setup:

> ```
> create table t1
> as
> select level as id, mod(level, 2) as val, mod(level, 2) as col
> from dual
> connect by level < 4;
>
> create table t2
> as
> select level as id2, mod(level, 2) as val2, mod(level, 2) as col2
> from dual
> connect by level < 5;
>
> create table t3
> as
> select level as id3, mod(level, 2) as val3, mod(level, 2) as col3
> from dual
> connect by level < 6;
> ```

Usage:

> ```
> create function f_union_tables
> return varchar2 sql_macro(table)
> as
>   l_sql varchar2(4000);
> begin
>   /*
>     Below query emulates dynamic SQL with union
>     of counts per columns COL* and VAL* per table,
>     assuming you have only one such column in a table
>   */
> select
>   listagg(
>     replace(replace(
>     /*Get a count per the second and the third column per table*/
>     q'{
>     select '$$table_name$$' as table_name, $$agg_cols$$, count(*) as cnt
>     from $$table_name$$
>     group by $$agg_cols$$
>     }',
>     '$$table_name$$', table_name),
>     '$$agg_cols$$', listagg(column_name, ' ,') within group(order by column_name asc)
>     ),
>     chr(10) || ' union all ' || chr(10)
>   ) within group (order by table_name) as result_sql
>
>   into l_sql
>
> from user_tab_cols
> where regexp_like(table_name, '^T\d+$')
>   and (
>     column_name like 'VAL%'
>     or column_name like 'COL%'
>   )
> group by table_name;
>
>   return l_sql;
> end;/
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from f_union_tables()
> ```

| TABLE_NAME | COL | VAL | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| T1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| T2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| T2 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| T3 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| T3 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bBT7qlmD)

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.
I have update the questing and added timings screenshot from PLSQL_PROFILER and it seems like with nested tables, multiset and forall 40 secs and being saved.

Comment: @mradul it's hard to explain the difference without actual code. The main time should be consumed by reading and writing, which is the same in both cases, but I doubt that query generation takes 40 seconds (at least it does not in the fiddle).